# Flutter firebase_admob not working on iOS with default app install

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, admob

Steps to reproduce:

> 1. create a default app in Android Studio
> 2. build and run the app successfully in iOS simulator through Android Studio
> 3. add dependency `firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+2` in pubspec.yaml
> 4. app builds successfully but crashes on startup
> 5. follow instructions to add `GADApplicationIdentifier` with test ID code into `ios/Runner/info.plist` file

The app still crashes on startup. Instructions were followed for setting up on iOS as detailed here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob.

As far as I can see, I've done everything as instructed so no idea why it doesn't work with a default app.

The error I get after all steps above is:

```
Xcode build done. 8.5s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
6.4.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
6.4.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
6.4.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
6.4.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.

*** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000113b521bb
__exceptionPreprocess + 331 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001130f0735
objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000113b52015 +
[NSException raise:format:] + 197 3 Runner 0x000000010bd33af0 +[FIRApp
configure] + 576 4 Runner 0x000000010bd7f1c5 -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin
init] + 261 5 Runner 0x000000010bd7ef2e +[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin
registerWithRegistrar:] + 78 6 Runner 0x000000010bd333fb +
[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 123 7 Runner <…>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase to your project.

Check this links:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: The installation instruction don't mention that though? There's no mention of `GoogleService-Info.plist` anywhere: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

Comment: It's suposed to follow this installation guide before add any plugin. Just add the file and all will be fine. I added the file inside the folder ./ios and ./ios/runner

Comment: I've added lots of other packages by just following the instructions. I never needed anything else. So I need to create a firebase project?? Are you sure? Can't believe they wouldn't mention that in the installation instructions...?

Comment: Ok, my guess was that you used firebase_admob since you were using a firebase project. If u want to use admob without firebase use another plugin like:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_admob#-readme-tab-

Comment: No it's just the most popular admob package for flutter. If you search for implementing Admob with Flutter they almost always use firebase_admob...regardless of whether you are using firebase already or not. I tried using the other admob package you suggest `flutter_admob` but it makes my app huge....check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032727/flutter-huge-app-size-in-ios-compared-with-react-native-original

Comment: So if you want to use firebase_admob just create a new firebase project and add the GoogleService-Info.plist into your project.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this medium post](https://medium.com/@ryanwaldorf/how-to-setup-flutter-with-firebase-for-ios-791f0710707e) is the most comprehensive ios Firebase setup guide, however point 1 can be skipped - I have an app using `firebase_admob 0.8.0+3` and it works flawlessly under iOS, once all other steps are completed.